# My widget is not in the center event it is wrapped with center widget

Tags: flutter

I wrapped my column widget with a center widget. But my column is just centered horizontally and not in the vertical. How I can make it in the center in the horizontal and vertical?
[Image: How it looks on the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS7c4.png)

Code:

```
body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'IMPOS?',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red[600],
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'IMPOS?',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red[600],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to also set your `crossAxisAlignment` to center on your `Column`:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` to your Column, this will force the column to have as much space as the children will occupy.